# Problema al crear constraint en Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, tablas

Hola estoy intentando crear estas tablas en SQL

```
create table Clientes(
                      Tdoc varchar (10),
                      Ndoc int,
                      Nombre varchar(30),
                      Apellido varchar(30),
                      constraint p_key primary key(Tdoc,Ndoc)
                      )


create table Vendedor(
                      Tdoc varchar (10),
                      Ndoc int,
                      Nombre varchar(30),
                      Apellido varchar(30),
                      constraint p_key_ve primary key(Tdoc,Ndoc)
                      )

create table Venta( tdoc_vend varchar (10),
                    ndoc_vend int,
                    tdoc_cli varchar (10),
                    ndoc_cli int,
                    nro_fac int,
                    fecha date,
                    tipo_pago int,
                    constraint venta_key primary key (tdoc_vend, ndoc_vend, tdoc_cli, ndoc_cli, nro_fac),
                    constraint t_doc foreign key (tdoc_vend, ndoc_vend) references Vendedor (Tdoc, Ndoc),
                    constraint cli foreign key (tdoc_cli, ndoc_cli) references Clientes (Tdoc, Ndoc)
                    )

create table Producto ( id int primary key,
                        descripcion varchar (20),
                        precio float)

create table TPago ( id int primary key,
                     descripcion varchar (20))

create table Detalle_venta (nro_fact int,
                            id_prod int,
                            cantidad int,
                            constraint keyDv primary key (nro_fact, id_prod),
                            constraint nrofac foreign key (nro_fact) references Venta(nro_fac),
                            constraint idpro foreign key (id_prod) references Producto(id)
                            )
```

El problema es cuando intento crear la ultima tabla, donde me sale el siguiente error

```
Mens. 1776, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 880
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Venta' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'nrofac'.
Mens. 1750, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 880
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

Comment: Pero venta tiene una primary compuesta, por ende la foreign debe ser compuesta tambien. Ahora, por que utilizas unas primary key tan complejas? te recomendaria en ventas dejar todos esos campos como una unique key y asignar una primary key autoincremental, asi la puedes relacionar con tu campo nro_fac. Ahora, hay que revisar un poco tu modelo entidad relacion puede ser que la normalizacion que manejas no este del todo optima

Answer (score 0):

lo que sucede es que en la tabla `Ventas` estas a asignando como llave primaria `nro_fac`

```
constraint venta_key primary key (tdoc_vend, ndoc_vend, tdoc_cli, ndoc_cli, nro_fac),
```

, despues en la tabla `Detalle_venta` estas asignado una llave llave primaria que es `nro_fac` y luego tratas de poner una llave foranea con ese campo

```
 constraint nrofac foreign key (nro_fact) references Venta(nro_fac),
```

por lo cual una llave foranea solo de da desde una llave primaria a un campo del mismo tipo.

espero te haya ayudado. By srJJ
postd: si te ayudo marcala como resuelta

Comment: El error va por el lado de las llaves compuestas, si la primary tiene 3 campos, la foreign debe tener 3 campos.